# Kendo Dropdown Value id not updating the GRID after ADD/EDIT

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have using the below code for Kendo Grid. I'm using six dropdown and one text box input fields. It works perfectly fine for add, edit & delete operations and also reflect the records into database, but the only problem is after add and edit operation, value of dropdown field not displaying the grid but values are into database.

```js
$("#riskassessment").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: { url: serverUrl + "/RiskAssessment/GetRiskAssessment", type: "GET", dataType: 'json', cache: false },
                update: {
                    url: serverUrl + "/RiskAssessment/PostRiskAssessmentEdit",
                    type: "POST"                    
                },
                create: {
                    url: serverUrl + "/RiskAssessment/PostRiskAssessmentAdd",
                    type: "POST"                   
                },
                destroy: { url: serverUrl + "/RiskAssessment/DeleteRiskAssessment", type: "POST", cache: false }               
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "RiskAssessmentConfigId",
                    fields: {
                        RiskAssessmentConfigId: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                        ComponentId: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
                        XCHKZEROId: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
                        YieldId: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
                        CVALBEId: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
                        CVALFQAID: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true } },
                        RiskId: { editable: true, nullable: false, validation: { required: true } }
                    }
                }
            },
            sort: [{ field: "ComponentId", dir: "asc" }],
            pageSize: 5
        },
        columns: [
                { field: "ComponentId", title: "Component", editor: ComponentDropDownEditor, width: "150px", template: "#= GetGeneralDDLabelName(ComponentId) #" },
                { field: "YieldId", title: "Yield", editor: YieldDownEditor, width: "150px", template: "#= GetGeneralDDLabelName(YieldId) #" },
                { field: "CVALBEId", title: "CVAL BE", editor: CVALBEDropDownEditor, width: "150px", template: "#= GetGeneralDDLabelName(CVALBEId) #" },
                { field: "CVALFQAID", title: "CVAL FQA", editor: CVALFQADropDownEditor, width: "150px", template: "#= GetGeneralDDLabelName(CVALFQAID) #" },
                { field: "XCHKZEROId", title: "XCHKZERO", editor: XCHKZERODropDownEditor, width: "150px", template: "#= GetGeneralDDLabelName(XCHKZEROId) #" },
                { field: "RiskId", title: "Risk", editor: RiskDropDownEditor, width: "150px", template: "#= GetRiskDDLabelName(RiskId) #" },
                { field: "Remarks", title: "Remarks" },
                { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "180px" }],
        editable: "popup",
        pageable: true,
        sortable: true,
        toolbar: ["create"],
        change: onChange,
        RequestEnd: onGridDataSourceRequestEnd
    });
```

After Save or Edit record display like below.

[image]

Any one please help me to fix this issue.

I have also added RequestEnd event to refresh the grid, but event not triggering.

```
function onGridDataSourceRequestEnd(e) {
    alert(e.type);
    if (e.type == "update") {
        $("#riskassessment").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside column Fields instead of giving

```
template: "#= GetGeneralDDLabelName(YieldId) #"
```

try giving

```
template: "#=YieldId#"
```

and coming to RequestEnd syntax error its

```
requestEnd:function(e)
```

Comment: I am not able to comment on your question thats y i provided answer recently i faced this issues I can try my best to help you

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem.

Following was my understanding of the problem and solution:

Basically dropdown editor is a function that builds a drop down from external data source. So, it works fine. However, for the **template** definition to work in (field.property) format, the server must return the value as a class for this field and not a simple text.

So you may return following format from your server side service:

```
{"ComponentId":{"id":"YOURID","name":"YORNAME"}}
```

Furthur you may use object as

```
template: "#= ComponentId.name #"  //or "#= GetGeneralDDLabelName(ComponentId.name) #" according your code
```